# Composite Shims on Short Retaining Wall

Tags: retaining-wall

Would there be an issue with using composite shims to help level one layer of block on top of another?

**Other possible relevant info**

- I am using 6in x 12in retaining wall block.
- Max height is 3 blocks tall (plus capstone)
- Using 3/4 in agg to backfill behind the block, inside the block cavity, and under the 1st layer of block.
- Ground and 3/4 in agg stone are tamped and leveled prior to block placement
- Capstones will be secured using landscape block adhesive.
- I will probably squirt some landscape block adhesive into any gaps created around the shims.
- I would expect to use shims on maybe 3 bricks where it's been tough to transition from one layer to another due to the hill slope.
- Checking to make sure the shims do not cause any block wiggle once installed.

[image: Wall]

[image: Shim Placement]

[image: Shim]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These blocks are designed to be installed loose,  and that tree's roots are going to win any disagreement they have with them.  trying to make a permanent structure from  these semi-permanent retaining blocks seems futile, especially in this location.

plastic, fibre-cement, or slate (etc) shims will not cause any significant weakening of the wall.